# PDF calling twice in IE

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am facing an issue with PDF loading in my page.

I am using object tag to embed PDF,

```
<object data='addDocs.do?viewName=PDF&id="+$("#pdfId").val()+"&File=regDoc.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='95%' height='750'>&nbsp;</object>
```

This is getting called twice when using IE Browser.

I did some search on the same question and tried with `response.setDateHeader("Expires", 30000);`. No Luck.

I can't use IFRAME because I need to open the links inside the PDF in the same window rather than inside IFRAME.

When using EMBED tag to load PDF, If the size of the PDF is larger then browser is freezing.

So, please help me out on calling PDF only once in IE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $("#pdfId") object? are you sure $("#pdfId").val() doesn't call pfd ?

Comment: its just an string variable. Ya, I am sure. Also, just for an update I hardcoded the ID and tested as well. Still getting call twice.

Comment: did you try other browsers? same for all??

Comment: In Firefox it is calling once.. In IE it is calling twice